# .htaccess rewrite rules misbehaving

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pageNotFound.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/message/?$ message.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
#
#RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1&content=$2 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^story/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ blog_post.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^forums/questions/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/edit/?$ question_edit.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^forums/questions/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ question.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^forums/contribution/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/edit/?$ contribution_edit.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^forums/contribution/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ contribution.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
#
RewriteRule ^forums/tags/([a-z-]+)/?$ allTags.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
#
```

Above is my `.htaccess` file and I am using WAMP.

At first when I did this, everything works fine, but later on, some URLs started misbehaving for example if I type in `localhost/profile/debbie` after the page finishes loading the url changes to `localhost/profile/Debbie/?u=debbie`, though the page contents work fine. I just don't know why. But if I do something like `localhost/profile/the_king` the url remains the same after loading.

But later on the if I do this `localhost/profile/the_king` I started getting an error message of  `undefined index u`

Secondly I have a Subdomain under WAMP for my mobile site which uses an IP address of `192.168.106.1` and I use a duplicate of the above `.htaccess` file for it,  but if I do this `192.168.106.1/profile/the_king` it just get back my `pageNotFound.php` error page back.

This is really getting me angry because I watched some video tutorials and I did exactly what they did but I just don't know why mine is misbehaving

**Edit** here is my configuration for my Subdomain

```
# Tells Apache to identify which site by name
NameVirtualHost *:80
# Tells Apache to serve the default WAMP Server page to "localhost"
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost> 
# Tells Apache to serve Client 1's pages to "client1.localhost"
# Duplicate and modify this block to add another client
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
# The name to respond to
ServerName localhost
# Folder where the files live
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
# A few helpful settings...
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile/">
Allow from all
Order Allow,Deny
# Enables .htaccess files for this site
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.1>
# The name to respond to
ServerName localhost
# Folder where the files live
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
# A few helpful settings...
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
Allow from all
Order Allow,Deny
# Enables .htaccess files for this site
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost 192.168.106.1>
# The name to respond to
ServerName m.localhost
# Folder where the files live
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
# A few helpful settings...
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile/">
Allow from all
Order Allow,Deny
# Enables .htaccess files for this site
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sounds like those rewrites are done via external redirects now. This may be necessary if you have some effect that changes (or appears to change) the domain name somehow. Might be another rewriting rule somewhere or an internal setting in some application.

Comment: I deleted all `.htaccess` files under my WAMP folder

Comment: Do you have such rules in your http servers host definitions (where they belong anyway)? Or some more complex host setups?

Comment: No, my host file just comprises of my domain setup

Comment: What do you mean by "my host file"?

Comment: I mean `C://windows/System32/drivers/etc/host`

Comment: That certainly is _not_ your http servers host definition.

Comment: Okay, please how can I check for that?

Comment: You yourself wrote that you are using a "subdomain" for your http server. I assume you refer to a host name with that, since most likely you did not reserve an additional domain name under some second level domain offering further fine grained registration. So you probably have configured that host yourself in your http server. That setup is what I refer to.

Comment: Yes, I configured that in my `httpd.conf` file. I will edit my question to show my configuration for that

Comment: @arkascha I have added my configuration

Comment: I assume you have a conflict between those different virtual hosts you define (_why do you do that_?). Depending on your network topology this might end up in redirections between separate hosts which is only possible using _external redirects_, so by changing the visible URL in the browser. I suggest you use a more simple host setup. If you _really_ need such separate hosts, then certainly they should not deliver the same content, so overlap. That simply does not make any sense.

Comment: So I guess I should remove the second Virtual host setup seeing that it has the same IP address as the first but different setup